# Can I co-own property in UK as a house wife?

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage

Asking on someone's behalf but I will act as them.

My husband owns a house in UK with his brother, both of them are on mortgage as well. Even though my husband pays all the mortgages his brother now wants to take his name off mortgage and also from house ownership.

***Is it possible for me to co-own house as a housewife***, I don't work at all but take care of children. My husband is trying to get a new deal of mortgage on his name. so his brother will be out of question soon hopefully.

**Edit**

My husband's brother wants to take his name off from house & mortgage and we all are happy with this.

Comment: There are actually a few questions buried in what you're asking. Note that 'home ownership' is different than being a cosigner on a mortgage. Also note that whether you are 'able' to co-own the house, it is not clear how this would happen given the current co-ownership between the brothers.

Comment: Also - could you clarify who is trying to get whom off of the mortgage / house deed? Due to ambiguities in the English language it is not immediately clear to me who your husband's brother wants to get off the mortgage (himself? or your husband?).

Comment: So the brother wants to take his own name off of the title?  The pronouns make it a little confusing.

Comment: In the US that's done with a "quit-claim" deed. I don't know what the UK equivalent is.  Is there any equity in the house? Seems odd to just "give up" half ownership in a house.

Comment: The answer is most likely "yes" to all questions - yes the brother can give up his half - yes you can be put on the title - yes your husband can refinance the house in his name only (provided his credit is good enough). But I would talk to a bank and real estate attorney (independently - don't let one refer you to the other) in the UK to make sure nothing goes wrong.

Comment: This isn't the 19th century.  Housewives are actually allowed to own (or co-own) things now.

Comment: @SimonB but how, mortgage borkers says I can't :(

Comment: @Mathematics you cant jusy add yourself without the current owners agreeing.  If the brother is still on the title he would need to agree to put you on. That may be what the broker is referring to. Once the house is in your husband's name he can add you.

Comment: @DStanley Everyone is agreed, I will try to find out the exact reason broker said that, but I am pretty sure he said he just can't add me to house ownership if I am not part of mortgage deal with bank. Also could please tell me the name of process we could use for adding me to home ownership, thank you

Comment: Probably as @AakashM explained in his answer: the bank doesn't want to lend your husband money for a house he only owes half of. You will have to be on the mortgage. This shouldn't be a problem. Plenty of couples own property together where only one of them has income. If the mortgage broker can't find a bank that will allow it, get a better mortgage broker.

Answer (score 10):

The question isn't whether or not you can "co-own property as a housewife" - of course you can. The question is whether or not you can co-own property **that has a first mortgage on it that you are not a participant in**. And the answer to that is no.

The problem the bank has is this: As part of the deal by which the money was lent to buy the house, the bank acquired the [**first charge**](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/meaning-of-First%20Charge) on the property. This is what gives them the right to repossess in case of non-payment.

Now, at the moment your husband (call him H) and his brother (B) co-own the house and are also jointly and severally liable for the mortgage. Suppose it were possible for you to be added to the list of house owners, but not added to the mortgage. Then suppose H+B stop paying the mortgage. The bank would be entitled to repossess the house - but wait, you own a third of it and have no contractual relationship with the bank. What happens here?

This potential conflict is why your broker quite rightly said "he just can't add me to house ownership if I am not part of mortgage deal with bank". It's also why when one is buying a house, the mortgage provider is typically very interested indeed to learn about who will be living in the house, particularly adults, so as to be sure they are not acquiring property rights without mortgage responsibilities.

I don't know off the top of my head what you can do *simply* to resolve this problem. If B is (as you say) happy to relinquish his share of ownership, that's one thing - but you will also need to agree with the mortgage provider that the mortgage can be transferred to you+H, and that H's income alone is enough to meet their lending criteria. Given that H has been paying the mortgage without any contribution from B, this *shouldn't* be a problem, but you never know.

I would recommend talking to a solicitor (specialising in conveyancing), and then with their help talking to the bank. Expect fees to be involved, in the hundreds of pounds.